# Angularjs, Spring MVC and @ModelAttribute = null values

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am working on an application where the frontend uses Angularjs and the backend exposes REST-services using Spring MVC. I am trying to use $resource in AngularJS to save a new object but when it calls my Controller an empty(all variables are null) object is passed.

This is my method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/instance", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ActionResult createInstance(@ModelAttribute Instance instance) {
        logger.info(instance.toString());
        return ActionResult.SUCCESS;
    }
```

Here are some of the data that Chrome reports is beeing sent:

```
Request Method:POST    
Status Code:200 OK    
Request Headersview source    
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*    
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch    
Accept-Language:sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4    
Connection:keep-alive    
Content-Length:229    
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Request Payloadview parsed
{"id":"ffde5029-32b4-407e-b6ed-0192fcc994fe","count":0,"events":[],"status":"STOPPED","name":"name1","deviceProductInfo":{"manufacturer":"ACME","model":"Analyzer 2000"},"enabled":false,"type":"ARCH2000","timeForLastActivity":"-"}
```

When I log the instance-object in my controller alls fields are empty:

```
Instance{count=0, id='null', events=[], status='null', name='null', deviceProductInfo=null, enabled=false}
```

Am I missing something or why is my Instance object not populated with the JSON-data being sent? Help greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This is my Instance-class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public class Instance {

    private int count;
    private String id;
    private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    private String status;
    private String name;
    private DeviceProductInfo deviceProductInfo;
    private boolean enabled;

    public Instance() {

    }

    public Instance(@JsonProperty("id") String id, String name, String status) {
        this.id = id;
        this.status = status;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public DeviceProductInfo getDeviceProductInfo() {
        return deviceProductInfo;
    }

    public void setDeviceProductInfo(DeviceProductInfo deviceProductInfo) {
        this.deviceProductInfo = deviceProductInfo;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return "ARCH2000";
    }

    public List<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Instance{" +
                "count=" + count +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", events=" + events +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", deviceProductInfo=" + deviceProductInfo +
                ", enabled=" + enabled +
                '}';
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getTimeForLastActivity() {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.events)) {
            return "-";
        } else {


            DateTime dateForLastEvent = events.get(events.size() - 1).getOccured();
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

            return dateTimeFormatter.print(dateForLastEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `Instance` class.

Comment: I updated my question with my Instance-class.

Comment: Don't use `@ModelAttribute`, use `@RequestBody` instead.

Comment: The solution suggested by M. Deinum worked.

Answer (score 1):

please try replace @ModelAttribute with @RequestBody. It worked to me.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody void add****(@RequestBody Good good) {

        System.out.println("");
    }.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitely add JSON as the type to be consumed:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/instance", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but unfortunataly this does not help. The values are still null in my Controller.